# Zend Framework remove or unset appended css file from headlink()

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to remove or unset a particular stylesheet that's been appended?

eg:

```
<?php 
// my layout file
     $this->headLink()
       ->appendStylesheet('/css/page/foo.css');

?>
```

Often i've appended stylesheets or added stylesheets but now i don't need in the view script for a particular context. Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you putting the ->appendStylesheet call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much your options with the current api is to overwrite the whole `headLink()` stack by calling `setStyleSheet()` in your controller/action/view. 
Another option would be to refactor and only add certain stylesheets when need for specific action/views.
I do believe that most people would just let it be, as the extra few bits a stylesheet consumes is usually not worth the cpu cycles to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `removeStylesheet()` or anything similar. This is mostly due to the reasons of that you should try to reduce the files needed to an absolut minimum my migrating your css files into one file.

It doesn't matter if the file is 20kb bigger, as long as it's just one request.

Then, if you have some special sites, e.g. sites with administrative parts, for such sites you can append an admin-stylesheet.

Just append what's needed!